# Add remove border on click

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add and remove the class .accord-header-border on .accord-header so that it shows and hides a border line. I can toggle it on and off on the click. The issue is how to add logic that removes it when I click on a different panel.

[View the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gaLvuac/3/) to see how this works...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function () {

        var im = $(this).find('img');
        $('.rotate2').not(im).removeClass('rotate2');
        im.toggleClass('rotate2');

    // The toggle on the border
        $(this).toggleClass('accord-header-border');


        if ($(this).next("div").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next("div").slideUp("normal");


        } else {
            $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("normal");
            $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: .removeClass('className');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `.not()` as you did for `rotate2`, see below code -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function () {

        var im = $(this).find('img');
        $('.rotate2').not(im).removeClass('rotate2');
        im.toggleClass('rotate2');

        //add accord-header-border to other elements
       $('.accordion .accord-header').not(this).addClass('accord-header-border');
    // The toggle on the border
        $(this).toggleClass('accord-header-border');


        if ($(this).next("div").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next("div").slideUp("normal");


        } else {
            $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("normal");
            $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a good solution however you will notice that if you view the JSFiddle (edited initial question) it does not remove the line when you click on another panel. https://jsfiddle.net/1gaLvuac/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the class from all the panels or from where ever you need it to be removed and then add on the panel on which is clicked. Like this below-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function () {
        //Added the below line to remove the class from all panels
        $('.accord-header-border').removeClass('accord-header-border');
        var im = $(this).find('img');
        $('.rotate2').not(im).removeClass('rotate2');
        im.toggleClass('rotate2');

    // The toggle on the border
        $(this).toggleClass('accord-header-border');


        if ($(this).next("div").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next("div").slideUp("normal");


        } else {
            $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("normal");
            $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`$('.accordion .accord-header').removeClass('accord-header-border');`

before

`$(this).toggleClass('accord-header-border');`

It will remove borders for all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasClass` method to check if the clicked item is the current item, and do different things depending on that:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('accord-header-border') {
  $(this).removeClass('accord-header-border');
} else {
  $(".accordion .accord-header.accord-header-border").removeClass('accord-header-border');
  $(this).addClass('accord-header-border');
}
```